# Imágenes aleatorias con Js

Tags: javascript

¿Cómo puedo hacer aparecer imágenes aleatorias(sin recargar la página) al presionar un botón con javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Que tal, prueba con este código de [http://www.forosdelweb.com/](http://www.forosdelweb.com/f4/imagen-aleatoria-pulsar-enlace-843812/)

```
function rand(n){
// creamos un numero al azar entre 1 y 10 (o cual sea la cantidad de imágenes)
 return(Math.floor(Math.random() * n + 1 ));
}
//guardas imagenes en el array
var cambia_imagen = new Array();
cambia_imagen[0] = "0.jpg";
cambia_imagen[1] = "1.jpg";
cambia_imagen[2] = "2.jpg";
cambia_imagen[3] = "3.jpg";
cambia_imagen[4] = "4.jpg";
cambia_imagen[5] = "5.jpg";
cambia_imagen[6] = "6.jpg";
cambia_imagen[7] = "7.jpg";
cambia_imagen[8] = "8.jpg";
cambia_imagen[9] = "9.jpg";



//la función para que al clickear establezca el source del tag imagem que tiene id "ia" (Imagen aleatoria)
//como no son tantas, puede que alguna vez se repita 2 veces la misma
//incluso, si usamos numeros para las imágenes, la script puede ser más sencilla


function cambiar(){
     document.getElementById("ia").src = cambia_imagen[rand(10)-1];
}
```

Tu HTML quedaría algo así:

```
<p><img id="ia" alt="Imagen aleatoria" src="5.jpg" /></p>

<button onclick="cambiar();">Cambiar imagen</button></p>
```

Por ultimo queda agregar que la función hay que llamarla una vez cuando carga la página

```
<body onload="cambiar()">
```

Comment: No me funciona :$

Comment: La imagen no me carga..

Comment: Tenga en cuenta que en la función cambiar en rand, tiene que ir con el valor total de las imágenes que vaya usted a cargar

Comment: podrias resolver ese problema usando el tamaño del arreglo directamente `cambia_imagen[rand(cambia_imagen.length)-1]`