# Imagenes aleatorias en HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

Que tal, ¿alguien por acá podría ayudarme a colocar un panel (`div`) con imágenes que cambien cada cierto tiempo? Ya probé con `<marquee>` pero no logro conseguir lo que quiero.

Aquí un ejemplo de lo que quiero lograr (es el que tiene fondo azul), muestra 3 imágenes de forma temporal. Agradeceré su ayuda.

http://www.videotour24.com/v2/src/main/main.php

Comment: Hola Yamarkus, bienvenido a Stackoverflow en español. Creo que olvidaste decir _qué habías intentando_, pero te invito a que sigas la guía [_"Cómo crear un ejemplo completo, mínimo y verificable"_]. Lo que quieres se llama "carrusel". Revisa las respuestas en este sitio, tal vez tu pregunta ya esté respondida.

Comment: @toledano Tenías razón, hay una pregunta similar, [Imágenes aleatorias con js](http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/21741/im%C3%A1genes-aleatorias-con-js) ... Digo similar porque este tiene la diferencia de que es cada cierto tiempo, y el otro solo una vez. Mi respuesta me quedó muy parecida incluso.

Answer (score 4):

Dejo una versión que no usa jQuery. Lo que intento hacer es insertar una imagen aleatoriamente en el `body`, en este ejemplo son 10 imágenes png, con nombre del 0 al 9, la imagen cambia cada 1 segundo, por eso puse `1000` como argumento a setTimeout, cada segundo equivale a mil milisegundos.

Esto es opcional, pero está bueno, el archivo del script y el HTML tendría que estar en el formato `UTF-8` para que puedan incluirse tildes (á é í ó ú), en mi ejemplo, el nombre de la variable `cantidadImágenes` lleva la tilde á.

No probé el código pero debería funcionar, solo si existen las imágenes relativamente al sitio.

```
function imagenAleatoria()
{
    var elemento=document.body
    var cantidadImágenes=10
    var aleatorio=Math.floor(Math.random()*cantidadImágenes)
    elemento.innerHTML="<img src=\""+aleatorio+".png\"></img>"
    setTimeout(imagenAleatoria,1000)
}
imagenAleatoria()
```

Answer (score 1):

Bienvenido a **StackOverflow**.

Un ejemplo sencillo desarrollado con jQuery

> Nota: Existe forma de crear estos mismo efectos solamente aplicando estilo css pero aplicarlo de aquella manera implica mucho código css es mejor apoyarse con javascript/jquery

```js
var numItems = $(".img-wrapper .img-responsive").length; //Cuenta las imágenes
var imageToDisplay = 0; //Inicia una imagen para mostrar(la primera)
$(".img-wrapper .img-responsive").eq(imageToDisplay).fadeIn(600); //Mostramos la imágen

setInterval(function () {

$(".img-wrapper .img-responsive").eq(imageToDisplay).fadeOut(600); //Ocultar imagen actual
imageToDisplay++; //inicia la siguiente imagen para visualizar

if (imageToDisplay == numItems) { //Si la imagen de la pantalla es igual al número de imágenes, se reiniciará desde el principio.
    imageToDisplay = 0;
}
$(".img-wrapper .img-responsive").eq(imageToDisplay).fadeIn(200); //Muestra la imagen siguiente.

}, 3000);
```

```css
.img-wrapper {
width:100%;
}
#page-body-bg {
width : 100%;
}
.img-responsive {
left:0;
position:absolute;
display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div style="overflow : hidden; ">
<div class="img-wrapper">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.videotour24.com/v2/upload/image/8.jpg" style=" left : 0; display : absolute;" />
    <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.videotour24.com/v2/upload/image/9.jpg" style=" left : 0; display : absolute;" />
    <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.videotour24.com/v2/upload/image/5.jpg" style=" left:0; display: absolute;"/>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Con esta parte queda mejor  .img-responsive {
width : 100%;
Height:200px;
left:0;
position:absolute;
dplay:none;
}

Answer (score 1):

Usando un [`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval) de JavaScript debería funcionar. Esta función repite una serie de comandos cada tanto tiempo como le indiques.

Un ejemplo de esto sería el siguiente:

```js
var vuelta = 0

var repetirVuelta = setInterval(function() {
  vuelta++
  console.log('esta es la vuelta ' + vuelta)
}, 1000)
```

Tomando en cuenta el ejemplo, se puede apreciar que esta función necesita que se le indique cada cuánto tiempo se va a realizar la función, siempre teniendo en consideración que el valor de 1000 es equivalente a 1 segundo.

Si en algún momento deseas detener este proseso, lo puedes hacer mediante la función [`clearInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/clearInterval), como en el siguiente ejemplo:

```js
var vuelta = 0

var intervalo = setInterval(function(){
   vuelta++
   console.log('Estas en la vuelta ' + vuelta)
}, 1000)

function stopInterval () {
  clearInterval(intervalo)
  console.log('El intervalo realizo un total de ' + vuelta + ' vueltas')
}
```

```html
<button id="mensaje" onclick="stopInterval()">Parar Intervalo</button>
```

Esta función necesita que le pases como parámetro el nombre que se le coloque a la variable que contiene el `setInterval`.